# Inequality contour integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given a curve $\gamma:[- \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathop{\gamma}\,(t):=2\exp(it)$, I want to show that
$$\left\vert\,\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^3+1} \mathrm{d}z\, \right| \le \frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: You could use partial fractions to calculate the integral exactly.

Comment: sorry, I do not see that

Comment: Just like for a real integral, $1/(z^3+1)=A/(z+1) + B/(z+\omega)+C/(z+\overline{\omega})$ integrates to the sum of three logs.  The complex log is $\log  r+i \theta$.  The answer below is better than my suggestion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$z=2e^{it}\;,\;\;-\frac\pi 6\le t\le\frac \pi 6\implies |z^3+1|=|8e^{3it}+1|=|(8\cos 3t+1)+8i\sin3t|=$$

$$\sqrt{64\cos^23t+16\cos 3t+1+64\sin^23t}=\sqrt{65+16\cos3t}\ge\sqrt{65+16\cos 3\frac\pi 6}=\sqrt{65}\ge 8$$

we get from Cauchy's Estimates:

$$\left|\;\int\limits_\gamma\frac{dz}{z^3+1}\;\right|\le\frac18\cdot\frac{4\pi}6=\frac{\pi}{12}$$